# Magento 2 : How to get invoice pdf file through API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, invoice-pdf, sales-invoice

In magento2 frontend, Login customer can download particular invoice of order from **My Account -> My Order -> Invoice Tab** Same Functionality we are developing in android app so my questions is how to get download link of invoice using API ?

Answer (score 3):

**View the invoice**
An invoice is structurally similar to an order, but an order contains more details.

**Endpoint**

```
GET <host>/rest/<store_code>/V1/invoices/3
```

**Headers**

```
Content-Type application/json

Authorization Bearer <administrator token>
```

**Response**

> You will use the order_item_id values to create a shipment in the next
>   step.

```
{
    "base_currency_code": "USD",
    "base_discount_amount": 0,
    "base_grand_total": 165,
    "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
    "base_shipping_amount": 5,
    "base_shipping_incl_tax": 5,
    "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0,
    "base_subtotal": 160,
    "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 160,
    "base_tax_amount": 0,
    "base_to_global_rate": 1,
    "base_to_order_rate": 1,
    "billing_address_id": 6,
    "can_void_flag": 0,
    "created_at": "2017-08-21 22:36:02",
    "discount_amount": 0,
    "email_sent": 1,
    "entity_id": 3,
    "global_currency_code": "USD",
    "grand_total": 165,
    "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
    "increment_id": "000000003",
    "order_currency_code": "USD",
    "order_id": 3,
    "shipping_address_id": 5,
    "shipping_amount": 5,
    "shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
    "shipping_incl_tax": 5,
    "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
    "state": 2,
    "store_currency_code": "USD",
    "store_id": 1,
    "store_to_base_rate": 0,
    "store_to_order_rate": 0,
    "subtotal": 160,
    "subtotal_incl_tax": 160,
    "tax_amount": 0,
    "total_qty": 9,
    "updated_at": "2017-08-21 22:36:03",
    "items": [
        {
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_price": 22,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 22,
            "base_row_total": 22,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 22,
            "base_tax_amount": 0,
            "entity_id": 3,
            "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "name": "Radiant Tee-M-Orange",
            "parent_id": 3,
            "price": 22,
            "price_incl_tax": 22,
            "product_id": 1553,
            "row_total": 22,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 22,
            "sku": "WS12-M-Orange",
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "order_item_id": 3,
            "qty": 1
        },
        {
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_price": 18,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 18,
            "base_row_total": 18,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 18,
            "base_tax_amount": 0,
            "entity_id": 4,
            "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "name": "Advanced Pilates & Yoga (Strength)",
            "parent_id": 3,
            "price": 18,
            "price_incl_tax": 18,
            "product_id": 49,
            "row_total": 18,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 18,
            "sku": "240-LV08",
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "order_item_id": 4,
            "qty": 1
        },
        {
            "base_price": 68,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 68,
            "entity_id": 5,
            "name": "Sprite Yoga Companion Kit",
            "parent_id": 3,
            "price": 68,
            "price_incl_tax": 68,
            "product_id": 51,
            "sku": "24-WG080-24-WG084-24-WG088-24-WG082-blue-24-WG086",
            "order_item_id": 5,
            "qty": 1
        },
        {
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_price": 27,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 27,
            "base_row_total": 27,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 27,
            "base_tax_amount": 0,
            "entity_id": 6,
            "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "name": "Sprite Stasis Ball 65 cm",
            "parent_id": 3,
            "price": 27,
            "price_incl_tax": 27,
            "product_id": 29,
            "row_total": 27,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 27,
            "sku": "24-WG082-blue",
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "order_item_id": 6,
            "qty": 1
        },
        {
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_price": 5,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 5,
            "base_row_total": 5,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 5,
            "base_tax_amount": 0,
            "entity_id": 7,
            "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "name": "Sprite Foam Yoga Brick",
            "parent_id": 3,
            "price": 5,
            "price_incl_tax": 5,
            "product_id": 21,
            "row_total": 5,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 5,
            "sku": "24-WG084",
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "order_item_id": 7,
            "qty": 1
        },
        {
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_price": 17,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 17,
            "base_row_total": 17,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 17,
            "base_tax_amount": 0,
            "entity_id": 8,
            "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "name": "Sprite Yoga Strap 8 foot",
            "parent_id": 3,
            "price": 17,
            "price_incl_tax": 17,
            "product_id": 34,
            "row_total": 17,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 17,
            "sku": "24-WG086",
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "order_item_id": 8,
            "qty": 1
        },
        {
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_price": 19,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 19,
            "base_row_total": 19,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 19,
            "base_tax_amount": 0,
            "entity_id": 9,
            "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "name": "Sprite Foam Roller",
            "parent_id": 3,
            "price": 19,
            "price_incl_tax": 19,
            "product_id": 22,
            "row_total": 19,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 19,
            "sku": "24-WG088",
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "order_item_id": 9,
            "qty": 1
        },
        {
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_price": 52,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 52,
            "base_row_total": 52,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 52,
            "base_tax_amount": 0,
            "entity_id": 10,
            "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "name": "Chaz Kangeroo Hoodie",
            "parent_id": 3,
            "price": 52,
            "price_incl_tax": 52,
            "product_id": 67,
            "row_total": 52,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 52,
            "sku": "MH01-S-Gray",
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "order_item_id": 10,
            "qty": 1
        },
        {
            "base_price": 0,
            "entity_id": 11,
            "name": "Chaz Kangeroo Hoodie-S-Gray",
            "parent_id": 3,
            "price": 0,
            "product_id": 56,
            "sku": "MH01-S-Gray",
            "order_item_id": 11,
            "qty": 1
        }
    ],
    "comments": []
}
```

Comment: In the question @Hiren have clearly mentioned that he needs it for customer login.
But endpoint you provided is for admin